# javascript await - how does it know the resolve result

Tags: javascript, async-await

From the tutorial:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function f1() {
  const x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
  console.log(x); // 10
}

f1();
```

I can see `10` going all the way into the `resolve(x)`, but it doesn't seem going out from the `resolve` function.  The document says `Promise.resolve` returns another `Promise`, but I don't see any code taking this new `Promise`.  I also don't see any code returning the `x` to the outer scope.  The document doesn't seem explaining this, or I just don't understand.

How does the `await` keyword know that the return value is `10`?

Comment: You are not calling Promise.resolve().... That would look like `function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) { return Promise.resolve(x); }` The Promise.resolve is a static method that returns a promise is automatically resolved.

Comment: There is no call to `Promise.resolve` in your code, only the *resolve argument to the Promise constructor callback*. Those are two different things. You are resolving the value of the Promise returned from `resolveAfter2Seconds` with the 10, and the `await` in `f1` "unwraps" it when it resolves.

Comment: `Promise.resolve` is not the same resolve function that is passed to the callback!

Comment: The `await` keyword uses the `then()` method to be informed when the promise resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `resolve` sets the promise's resolved value to what you pass to it, and `await` awaits until a promise is resolved (or rejected) and returns the resolved value (or throws, if the promise was rejected).

`Promise.resolve` is a different beast – it returns a promise that's *already* resolved.

Since you're passing a new function of your own devising to `new Promise`, you could name that `resolve` e.g. `ok`, if it makes things clearer: `new Promise((ok) => ok(8))` (but please don't; the convention is `resolve`).

You don't really need to know what exactly happens internally in your JavaScript engine for promises to work.

Answer (score 1):

> The document says Promise.resolve

Do not confuse the static `resolve` method of the `Promise` class with the function passed as the first argument to the function passed to the `new Promise` constructor.

---

> I also don't see any code returning the x to the outer scope

Because `x` isn't returned.

You can't return from an asynchronous operation. That is why promises exist in the first place.

---

`resolveAfter2Seconds` returns a promise.

That promise is resolved with the value of `x`.

`await` sends `f1` to sleep until the promise on its RHS resolves.

When it does, it becomes the resolved value which is assigned to the other `x`.